Blender 4.0.2 is not using gpu
I'm trying to render a project of 600 frames, and it took more than 6h to reach 50% of the total render when I checked it was using 100% of my CPU

and here are the project setting



This has been asked before, see the linked post. Also you should be using Optix with your graphics card
